# How to dynamically align image in a div?

Tags: asp.net, image, dynamic, alignment

I am developing a cms website. In this the admin can add logo to the website's home page and can tell the position of the image whether it should be displayed left,right or to the middle of the home page .

In the home page the image is displayed inside a div.I know how to display the image from the database,but not sure how to set its position dynamically?

However i tried the code but not worked correctly?

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptHeaderMenu" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>                    
                    <div align='<%Eval("IMAGE_POSITION")%>'>
                     <img src='<%Eval("IMAGE_URL")%>' />                                 
                    </div>                     
            </ItemTemplate>                
  </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: can you give us any code example you've tried?

Comment: I've modified the qn.Kindly look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

html:

```
<div id="div1" runat="server">
  <img id="img1" runat="server" />
</div>
```

code behind:

```
string floatPosition = <put database value here>
img1.Style.Add("float", floatPosition);
```

The sample code is not tested. You may have to make required adjustments.

**Updated sample code as per your given sample:**

Use panel to wrap an image (inside the Repeater's ItemTemplate) for easy access from server side. It would be rendered as a div on client side.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptHeaderMenu" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptHeaderMenu_OnItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" />
                      <img src='<%Eval("IMAGE_URL")%>' />
                    </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

In repeater's OnItemDataBound event (code behind):

```
protected void rptHeaderMenu_OnItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{
    string floatPosition = <put database value here>

    Panel Panel1 = e.Item.FindControl("Panel1") as Panel
    Panel1.Style.Add("float", floatPosition);
}
```

Comment: I think there is no center property for float.So instead of float i used the horizontal align property of panel.Thanks for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a serverside `image` control. store the alignment data in a `string` variable. Put the alignment variable in a `switch case` statement and add required style to the image depending upon the case.

Check this link to know how to add the style dynamically.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17ysx206(v=vs.85).aspx

Also check this link

[C# Adding style to a control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290112/c-sharp-adding-style-to-a-control)