# Editing elements style asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

So I have a progress bar which has an initial width which in this case is 40% and also an aria-valuenow="40":

```
<div class="progress">
 <div id="progress_bar" runat="server" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
 </div>
</div>
```

However when a user clicks a button I want to increment the width and the aria-valuenow to 50, is this possible in the code behind? So far I have:

```
protected void addTen_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  progress_bar.Style.Add("width", 50);
}
```

Surely my code is just constantly adding a new attribute? I just want to edit the current attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as [the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290112/c-sharp-adding-style-to-a-control) says, the **`Style.Add()`** function does not blindly add an attribute - it checks first if it exists, and if it does, it just modifies the value. Thus, your code is pretty good. :)

```
progress_bar.Style.Add("width", 50);
progress_bar.Style.Add("aria-valuenow", 40); // or whatever value you want
```

read more about the style attribute [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.style.width(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: How about the `aria-valuenow` attribute?

Comment: @mogorilla [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-valuenow_attribute) says it's just the same. :)